# Error in crossprod(test$inc_rat, nation_agegroup2010$total_prop) : non-conformable arguments

Tags: boot

I run the following lines to obtain the bootstrapped standardized rate for a group of people, but it return a error that I can't solve after a couple of days.

> Error in crossprod(test$inc_rat, nation_agegroup2010$total_prop) : 
>     non-conformable arguments

```
# to build the dataset
ZN_2011NGT_ADA <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
age_rage_ZN <- c("2", "3", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "3", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5")
zzz <- data.frame(ZN_2011NGT_ADA, age_rage_ZN)

# define the function for bootstrap
ZN_boot <- function(total_dat, rows){
data <- total_dat[rows,]
test <- merge(aggregate(data$ZN_2011NGT_ADA, by = list(age = data$age_rage_ZN), length), 
            aggregate(data$ZN_2011NGT_ADA, by = list(age = data$age_rage_ZN), sum), 
            by = 'age')
test$inc_rat <- test$x.y/test$x.x
return(crossprod(test$inc_rat, nation_agegroup2010$total_prop))}

# to run bootstrap
library(boot)
set.seed(1234
boot(data = zzz, statistic = ZN_boot, R = 5000)
```

The purpose of this block of codes is to get the bootstrapped rate (the value that returned in the function after bootstrapping in the boot function). I run similar codes on other datasets and it turned out to be fine. I am wondering why the last code always reports the above mentioned error? Can anyone be of help?